# Which programming languages require an IDE?

Tags: programming-languages, ide

I was reading through an answer to a question about an IDE for Go that triggered this question.

I was trying to think of a language that 'required' an IDE, but could not come up with one.

Comment: Can somebody clue me in on how to convert this Q to a community wiki?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50312/167837 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72908/167837

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the "graphical languages" more or less require an IDE. They aren't particularly popular at the moment, but the general idea is a "language" where you create programs by drawing some sort of diagram. Depending on the intended market, you frequently see something with a flavor or UML or ERD or even flowcharting, depending on the intended market, age of the tool, and level of <strike>obfuscation</strike> versatility and ease of use the inventor/vendor desires.

While most of these allow you to *store* the data in some sort of more or less textual format, they consider the diagram (of whatever sort) to *be* the language, and anything else is only a way of storing/recreating the diagram.

Comment: I'm torn by this answer - one the one hand, +1 for mentioning graphical languages (I was about to if no-one else had), but on the other hand -1 for suggesting they're unpopular: speaking as an engineer, quite a lot of instrumentation and control is done with graphical languages ([LabView](http://www.ni.com/labview/), [IEC 61131-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61131-3) LDs, [Simulink](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink/), etc).

Answer (score 0):

Some types of [4G Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language) would probably come up as requiring an IDE (being an IDE themselves).

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0):

All Smalltalks I know of except for GNU Smalltalk are very deeply integrated with their development environments.